# How to get the ID of a newly created subdocument using graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

This is a frustrating one because I've been looking and can't seem to find any answers that are specifically what I need (curse of my life) anyways. Basically I am using React and graphql where I am trying to insert a clock out time in reference to a particular clock in time. So I have my schema for this all working and if I get the ID of the clock in time (it is a subdocument) I can successfully update the subdocument with the appropriate clock out time, however, I cannot for the life of me determine how, in this particular set up, to get the newly created subdocument without a whole bunch of nonsense which isn't scalable. Here is the resolver I'm working with:

```
        clockIn: async (parent, args, context) => {
          if (context.user) {
            const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              {_id: context.user._id },
              { 
                clockedIn: true,
                $push: {
                  hoursWorked: {
                    clockedInTime: args.clockedInTime,
                    forDate: new Date(parseInt(args.clockedInTime)).toDateString()
                  },
                },
              },
              {new: true}
            )
            .select('-__v -password')

            return updatedUser;
          }
          throw new AuthenticationError('You must be Logged In')
        },
        clockOut: async (parent, args, context) => {
          if (context.user) {
            var updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              { _id: context.user._id},
              { clockedIn: false},
              {new: true}
            )
            .select('-__v -password')
            
            updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              {_id: context.user._id, "hoursWorked._id": args.clockedId},
              {
                  "hoursWorked.$.clockedOutTime": args.clockedOutTime
              },
              {new: true}
              )
              .select('-__v -password')

            return updatedUser;
          }

          throw new AuthenticationError('You must be Logged In')
        },
```

from the client side I am doing this (where I need the newly created ID of the clock in to populate the handleClockedOut variable clockedId). Unfortunately the response returns all of the items in the subdocument and not just the newly created one

```
const [ currentClockedInId, setCurrentClockedInId ] = useState('')

const handleClockIn = async (dbInTime) => {
        try {
            let response = await sendClockIn({
                variables: {
                    clockedInTime: dbInTime.getTime().toString()
                }
            });
            setCurrentClockedInId(response)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }

    const handleClockOut = async (dbOutTime) => {
        try {
            await sendClockOut({
                variables: {
                    clockedId: '63a9df37a3c0ea4737fa7967',
                    clockedOutTime: dbOutTime.getTime().toString()
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }


<section>
        {clockedIn? (
            <button onClick={() => {setClockedIn(false); handleClockOut(new Date())}}>Clock Out</button>
        ) : (
            <button onClick={() => {setClockedIn(true); handleClockIn(new Date())}}>Clock In</button>
        )}
        </section>
```

the client side mutations looks like this

```
export const CLOCK_IN = gql`
  mutation clockIn($clockedInTime: String!) {
    clockIn(clockedInTime: $clockedInTime) {
      _id
      hoursWorked {
        _id
        clockedInTime
        forDate
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const CLOCK_OUT = gql`
  mutation clockOut($clockedId: String!, $clockedOutTime: String!) {
    clockOut(clockedId: $clockedId, clockedOutTime: $clockedOutTime) {
      _id
      hoursWorked {
        clockedOutTime
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and the server side mutations look like this:

```
type WorkingHoursT {
    _id: ID
    clockedInTime: String
    clockedOutTime: String
    forDate: String
}

type User {
    _id: ID
    username: String
    email: String
    clockedIn: Boolean
    payAmount: String
    hoursWorked: [WorkingHoursT]
}
type Mutation {
    clockIn(clockedInTime: String!): User
    clockOut(clockedId: String!, clockedOutTime: String!): User
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I get more frustrated the further I look and everything references nothing close to what I'm looking at, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that for the `clockIn` mutation at least you return a `WorkingHoursT` object instead of the user.

```
clockIn(clockedInTime: String!): WorkingHoursT
```

Then you can get the `_id` of the `WorkingHoursT` object directly as a consequence of your mutation.

If you don't already have the user at that point then you could write a separate query to just fetch the user and run it at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately that returns a "ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 400". the WorkingHoursT is a subdocument and Schema only it's not modeled so I don't think it will return anything

Comment: As well altering the client side mutation to return just the ID makes it work but again it's just the user ID and not the working hours ID

Comment: You'll have to change the mutation code on the server.

Comment: change it to what? I already made it return the WorkingHoursT on the server "clockIn(clockedInTime: String!): WorkingHoursT"

Comment: No, the resolver code itself, not the query definition in the typedefs. The code that creates the working hours in your db.